Error when running org-contacts: org-contacts--candidate: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p
I'm trying to use org-contacts with Emacs and org-mode but are getting an error using the basic search command, org-contacts.
After installing org-contacts from melpa, and with this Emacs config:
(use-package org-contacts  
   :ensure t  
   :custom  
   (org-contacts-files '("~/org/contacts.org")))  

and this first test entry in the contacts.org file:
* Joe Blog  
  :PROPERTIES:  
  :TEL: +1 650 123 4567  
  :EMAIL:    joeblog@gmail.com  
  :URL:  
  :NOTES: Nice Guy  
  :END:  

calling M-x org-contacts, gives this error (debugger Backtrace)
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p (headline (:raw-value "Joe Blog" :begin 46 :end 212 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin 57 :contents-end 212 :robust-begin nil :robust-end nil :level 1 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :post-blank 0 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 46 :TEL "+1 650 123 4567" :EMAIL "joeblog@gmail.com" :URL "" :NOTES "Nice Guy" :ID "e74e91ec-9d87-4624-8ef0-71d48dccf341" :title "Joe Blog" :mode first-section ...)))
org-entry-properties((headline (:raw-value "Joe Blog" :begin 46 :end 212 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin 57 :contents-end 212 :robust-begin nil :robust-end nil :level 1 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :post-blank 0 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 46 :TEL "+1 650 123 4567" :EMAIL "joeblog@gmail.com" :URL "" :NOTES "Nice Guy" :ID "e74e91ec-9d87-4624-8ef0-71d48dccf341" :title "Joe Blog" :mode first-section ...)) standard)
org-contacts--candidate((headline (:raw-value "Joe Blog" :begin 46 :end 212 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin 57 :contents-end 212 :robust-begin nil :robust-end nil :level 1 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :post-blank 0 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 46 :TEL "+1 650 123 4567" :EMAIL "joeblog@gmail.com" :URL "" :NOTES "Nice Guy" :ID "e74e91ec-9d87-4624-8ef0-71d48dccf341" :title "Joe Blog" :mode first-section ...)))
#f(compiled-function (headline) #<bytecode -0x16cf8aeb8c5a3451>)((headline (:raw-value "Joe Blog" :begin 46 :end 212 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin 57 :contents-end 212 :robust-begin nil :robust-end nil :level 1 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :post-blank 0 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 46 :TEL "+1 650 123 4567" :EMAIL "joeblog@gmail.com" :URL "" :NOTES "Nice Guy" :ID "e74e91ec-9d87-4624-8ef0-71d48dccf341" :title "Joe Blog" :mode first-section ...)))
#f(compiled-function (--data) #<bytecode -0x1d67545669d4fcbf>)((headline (:raw-value "Joe Blog" :begin 46 :end 212 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin 57 :contents-end 212 :robust-begin nil :robust-end nil :level 1 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :post-blank 0 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 46 :TEL "+1 650 123 4567" :EMAIL "joeblog@gmail.com" :URL "" :NOTES "Nice Guy" :ID "e74e91ec-9d87-4624-8ef0-71d48dccf341" :title "Joe Blog" :mode first-section ...)))
mapc(#f(compiled-function (--data) #<bytecode -0x1d67545669d4fcbf>) ((headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) ...))
#f(compiled-function (--data) #<bytecode -0x1d67545669d4fcbf>)((org-data (:begin 1 :contents-begin 1 :contents-end 79758 :end 79760 :robust-begin 3 :robust-end 79756 :post-blank 2 :post-affiliated 1 :path nil :mode org-data ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) ...))
org-element-map((org-data (:begin 1 :contents-begin 1 :contents-end 79758 :end 79760 :robust-begin 3 :robust-end 79756 :post-blank 2 :post-affiliated 1 :path nil :mode org-data ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) (headline ...) ...) headline #f(compiled-function (headline) #<bytecode -0x16cf8aeb8c5a3451>))
org-contacts--candidates(("~/org/contacts.org"))
org-contacts--return-candidates(("~/org/contacts.org"))
org-contacts()
funcall-interactively(org-contacts)
command-execute(org-contacts record)
execute-extended-command(nil "org-contacts" "org")
funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-contacts" "org")
command-execute(execute-extended-command)


What's the version of Org mode? What's the version of org-contacts?

FWIW, it works fine for me with upstream Org mode (9.7pre) and with org-contacts-20230721.151 from MELPA. And I just noticed that there was another release three days ago.

Show the complete backtrace and enclose it in triple backticks: don't just show a partial backtrace.

Thanks @NickD.
I try to stay on stable versions:

Debian 12 stable with backport for emacs.
GNU Emacs 29.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version  3.24.38,
cairo version 1.16.0) of 2024-04-28, modified by Debian
Org mode version 9.6.15
org-contacts 20240430.114 ( have since installed the latest org-contacts of 20240516.955, with the same result.
I'll try to add the complete backtrace using your suggestion - I had problems with stackexchange refusing: "looks like spam"...


Sorry for the delay in getting back to you (I am an infrequent visitor to SO). You will need to upgrade Org mode to the current stable release (9.7.3) in order to make it compatible with org-contacts   20240430.114. Alternatively, you can go back to an older version of org-contacts: any version before 2024-04-09 should do it. The problem is that with commit 4e55b091c9d164bfdae1c5b93a3865e0499728b1, org-contacts became incompatible with Org mode versions < 9.7.

BTW, the dependency requirement was finally changed to Org mode 9.7  with this commit on 2024-05-21. It should have been changed when the breaking change was introduced on 2024-04-09, but things like that are easy to slip through the cracks.

Thank you @NickD.  You were spot on.  Problem resolved with the release of Org mode 9.7

Problem resolved with the release of Org mode 9.7. For details see comment from NickD.

Oftentimes, comments can (and are) removed by Moderators - please consider adding the details from the comments into this answer as appropriate - this ensures the relevant data from the comments won't be stripped out years later.
